# Whenever I use the Text object in JavaFX, all object overlap the text, even subsequent text objects

Tags: user-interface, javafx

Update: I am using JavaFX 13

This problem happens across all my JavaFX programs, but this is one example. A user is supposed to be able to select options for a custom milkshake then get a receipt when they checkout. All of the object referencing and MVC works as it is supposed to, but when displaying the information using Text objects (javafx.scene.text.Text), they are overlapped by other objects around them. In the second and third images, I have the occurrences circled.

[First launch of the program. The first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InvRv.png)

Here is the code for the text pane in the second image:
[After adding a few selections. The second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edZE9.png)

```
import Controllers.Controller;
import Entities.Milkshake;
import Interfaces.Observer;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;;

public class TextSummaryView extends AnchorPane implements Observer<Milkshake> {
    private Milkshake model;
    private Controller controller;
    private VBox iceCreamOptions;
    private VBox toppingOptions;
    private Text totalCost;

    private final double minHeight = 100.0;
    private final double minWidth = 50.0;


    public TextSummaryView() {
        super();

        iceCreamOptions = new VBox();
        toppingOptions = new VBox();
        totalCost = new Text("$0.00");
        Button checkout = new Button("Checkout");
        checkout.setOnAction(e -> controller.checkout());

        Text iceCreamText = new Text("Click '-' to remove\nCurrent Ice Cream Selections:");
        Text toppingText = new Text("Current Topping Selections");

        iceCreamOptions.getChildren().add(iceCreamText);
        toppingOptions.getChildren().add(toppingText);

        this.getChildren().addAll(checkout, iceCreamOptions, toppingOptions, totalCost);

        // Setting position of elements
        setBottomAnchor(checkout, this.getHeight()-5.0);
        setRightAnchor(checkout, this.getWidth()-5.0);

        setLeftAnchor(totalCost, 5.0);
        setBottomAnchor(totalCost, this.getHeight()-5.0);

        setTopAnchor(iceCreamOptions, 5.0);
        setLeftAnchor(iceCreamOptions, 5.0);

        setTopAnchor(toppingOptions, Math.max(40.0, iceCreamOptions.getHeight() + 10.0));
        setLeftAnchor(toppingOptions, 5.0);

        this.setMinHeight(minHeight);
        this.setMinWidth(minWidth);
    }

    /**
     * Sets what the observer will watch
     * @param obs An object that extends the Observable interface
     */
    public void setTarget(Milkshake obs){
        this.model = obs;
    }

    /**
     * Removes the object from target
     */
    public void removeTarget(){
        this.model = null;
    }

    /**
     * Called by observables to update the observer's data
     */
    public void update(){
        this.iceCreamOptions.getChildren().remove(1, this.iceCreamOptions.getChildren().size());
        this.toppingOptions.getChildren().remove(1, this.toppingOptions.getChildren().size());

        // Get Data
        ArrayList<String> iceCreams = model.getIceCreams();
        ArrayList<String> toppings = model.getToppings();

        // Update the ice cream selections
        int iceCreamIndex = 0;

        for (String ic: iceCreams) {
            AnchorPane selection = new AnchorPane();

            Button removeButton = new Button("-");
            Text iceCream = new Text(ic + ":");
            Text cost = new Text("$1.00");

            final int iceIndexFin = iceCreamIndex;

            removeButton.setOnAction(e -> controller.removeIceCream(iceIndexFin));

            selection.getChildren().addAll(removeButton, iceCream, cost);

            setLeftAnchor(removeButton, 5.0);
            setLeftAnchor(iceCream, 50.0);
            setTopAnchor(iceCream, selection.getHeight()/3);
            setLeftAnchor(cost, selection.getWidth()-5.0);
            setTopAnchor(cost, selection.getHeight()/3);

            this.iceCreamOptions.getChildren().add(selection);

            iceCreamIndex ++;
        }

        // Update the topping selections
        int toppingIndex = 0;

        for (String top: toppings) {
            AnchorPane selection = new AnchorPane();

            Button removeButton = new Button("-");
            Text topping = new Text(top + ":");
            Text cost = new Text("$0.50");

            final int topIndexFin = toppingIndex;

            removeButton.setOnAction(e -> controller.removeTopping(topIndexFin));

            selection.getChildren().addAll(removeButton, topping, cost);

            setLeftAnchor(removeButton, 5.0);
            setLeftAnchor(topping, 50.0);
            setTopAnchor(topping, selection.getHeight()/3);
            setLeftAnchor(cost, selection.getWidth()-5.0);
            setTopAnchor(cost, selection.getHeight()/3);

            this.toppingOptions.getChildren().add(selection);
            toppingIndex ++;
        }

        setTopAnchor(iceCreamOptions, 5.0);
        setLeftAnchor(iceCreamOptions, 5.0);

        setTopAnchor(toppingOptions, Math.max(40.0, iceCreamOptions.getHeight() + 10.0));
        setLeftAnchor(toppingOptions, 5.0);

        this.totalCost.setText( "$" + this.model.getCost() + "0");
    }

    public void setController(Controller controller){
        this.controller = controller;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the checkout screen. [Pressing the checkout button. All are different text objects in a VBox. The third image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdQSb.png)

```
import Entities.Milkshake;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CheckoutView extends Stage {
    VBox root = new VBox();

    public CheckoutView(Milkshake ms) {
        super();

        // Get Data
        ArrayList<String> iceCreams = ms.getIceCreams();
        ArrayList<String> toppings = ms.getToppings();

        // Update the ice cream selections
        int iceCreamIndex = 0;

        for (String ic: iceCreams) {
            AnchorPane selection = new AnchorPane();

            Text iceCream = new Text(ic + ":");
            Text cost = new Text("$1.00");

            final int iceIndexFin = iceCreamIndex;

            selection.getChildren().addAll(iceCream, cost);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(iceCream, 50.0);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(cost, this.getWidth()-5.0);

            this.root.getChildren().add(selection);

            iceCreamIndex ++;
        }

        // Update the topping selections
        int toppingIndex = 0;

        for (String top: toppings) {
            AnchorPane selection = new AnchorPane();

            Text topping = new Text(top + ":");
            Text cost = new Text("$0.50");

            selection.getChildren().addAll(topping, cost);

            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(topping, 50.0);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(cost, this.getWidth()-5.0);

            this.root.getChildren().add(selection);
            toppingIndex ++;
        }

        AnchorPane total = new AnchorPane();
        Text costTotal = new Text("$" +ms.getCost() + "0");
        total.getChildren().add(costTotal);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(total, this.getMaxWidth()-costTotal.getX());

        BorderPane exitOptions = new BorderPane();
        Button pay = new Button("Finish and Pay");
        Button ret = new Button("Return to Order");

        pay.setOnAction(e -> Platform.exit());
        ret.setOnAction(e -> this.close());

        exitOptions.setLeft(ret);
        exitOptions.setRight(pay);

        root.getChildren().add(exitOptions);

        this.setTitle("Checkout");
        this.setScene(new Scene(root));
    }

    public static void checkout(Milkshake ms) {
        CheckoutView check = new CheckoutView(ms);
        check.show();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for all your help! :)

Comment: Part of the problem may be the default [`Text#textOrigin`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/Text.html#textOriginProperty) value; you can try using `VPos.TOP` instead. However, your problem may also stem from using `AnchorPane` which does not automatically layout its children. You may want to consider using a more responsive layout or a combination of such layouts.

Comment: Also consider using `Label`s, which are managed, instead of `Text`s, which are not, if I remember correctly.